# Nhibernate - Cascading inverse doesn't get saved

Tags: nhibernate

I am building a small web application and using nhibernate as my DAL.
I have the following situation:

```
Father class - Profile Class:
{
    long ID
    string Name
    [A whole bunch of info]
    List<Voting> Votes
}

Son class - Votes Class:
{
     long id
     short rating
}
```

This is my mapping:

```
HasMany(o => o.Votes)
              .LazyLoad()
              .AsBag()
              .Inverse()
              .Cascade.All();
```

I want the following to happen:
Users will be able to rate a profile, and then all I need to do is merely call update on the profile itself, instead of sending a Save call on each Vote.

This i what I am currently doing:

```
var myProfile = new Profile();
myProfile.Rate(1,2);
myProfile.Rate(5,2);
myProfile.Rate(20,2);
Session.SaveOrUpdate(myProfile);
```

Sadly enough nothing gets saved. Why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If your one-to-many is mapped as inverse, the other side needs to know the parent object. So your Votes class needs a reference to a Profile (mapped as many-to-one).

You also have to make sure that this reference to the parent object is set in your code.

Additional note: Your code sample doesn't make much sense. If you create a new profile, you have to call Session.Save and not Session.Update.

Comment: You are right, I've updated it here and in my code to 'SaveOrUpdate'. I Tried to simplify things with a rather easier code sample, but missed that.